# Good way to generate "System" Unique Ids

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, identifier

I'm currently using Hibernate as JPA provider and I want to switch IDs generation from the persistence layer to the application layer.

My schema (on MySQL 5.7) is currently using a `BIGINT(20)` data-type for IDs, but I don't want to refactor to go for UUIDs.

So I thought that something like a "System" UID should be enough:

```
public static long getUID()
{
    long key = getSystemKey() << 56; // like 0x0100000000000000L;
    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis() << 12;
    int r = new Random().nextInt(0xFFF);
    long id = key + ts + r;

    return id;
}
```

The generated id is in the form

```
KK TTTTTTTTTTT RRR
```

where `getSystemKey()` [`K`] returns a unique  fixed byte for each "machine" the application is running on (it's declared inside the configuration file).

timestamp `ts` [`T`] is using 11 nybbles, ensuring enough millis to `2527-06-23 08:20:44.415`

random `r` [`R`] is used to add randomness per machine per millis (last 3 nybbles).

So I'm wondering if this way is consistent enough, what are pros and cons and if there's a better way.

Thanks

---

## UPDATE

I tested this method with 100 threads and 10,000 executions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    List<Callable<Long>> runners = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        runners.add(SUID::random);
    }

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    List<Future<Long>> results = pool.invokeAll(runners);
    pool.shutdown();

    int dups = 0;
    Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<>();
    for(Future<Long> future : results)
    {
        if(!ids.add(future.get()))
        {
            dups++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(dups);
}
```

I got around 6% of collisions.

So, the only way seems to use some synchronization:

```
public final class SUID
{
    private static final AtomicLong SEQUENCE = new AtomicLong(Config.getSystemKey() << 56 | System.currentTimeMillis() << 12);

    private SUID()
    {
        super();
    }
    
    public static long generate()
    {
        return SEQUENCE.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set the value of the Id column manually, it will not use any generators.

Comment: You have used "bytes" several times when you apparently mean nybbles (half-bytes).  `KK TTTTTTTTTTT RRR` as you have described it is actually 16 nybbles (4 bits × 16 = 64 bits), not 16 bytes (8 bits × 16 = 128 bits).

Comment: The algorithm you describe is somewhat reminiscent of the MySQL built-in function [`UUID_SHORT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short), which also returns a 64 bit unsigned integer and is similarly initialized with a value including `(@@SERVER_ID & 0xFF) << 56`... but it differs significantly, because it initializes the rest of the value using 32-bit `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() << 24` at server startup. It then behaves monotonically with each call, so return values between server restarts are consecutive. A mutex provides thread safety.

Comment: You're right, I started doing it in bytes, but ended in nybbles (odd ts)

Comment: Didn't know about it. It seems also a good compromise, but I'd like to avoid synchronization at all. Do you see any drawback?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "synchronization."  If you're thread-safe with this, it seems fine, but if multiple instances of this are running independently the same machine (same `K` value) then the millisecond precision and relatively small amount of randomness makes an occasional collision too likely for my taste.  Within any 1 second, there are only 1000 × 0xFFF = 4,096,000 possible values and that feels distinctly dirty to me.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm not thread-safe but I thought 4,096 possibilities per millis could be enough. I did a small test (see update) and I was wrong. The second method, similar to `UUID_SHORT()` seems the right way to go. Please post you comment as an answer so that I can accept it :) Thanks.